# stdc++.lib, stdc++fs.lib couldn't be opened with VS 22

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have following with a C++ project in VS 22 on windows:
I try to compile it in Release mode, but it says: 'stdc++.lib couldn't be opened'/'stdc++fs.lib couldn't be opened' (LNK1181).

So it doesn't find the library. But it should be included in the visual studio download or is it a linux specific library?

Thank you in advance

Comment: _"or is it a linux specific library?"_ with a `.lib` extension? Unlikely

Comment: are you following a tutorial for an older version of gcc? `stdc++fs` was a temporary libstdc++ library which doesn't exist in visual studio

Comment: If you are working with Visual Studio, then the build should not try to link against these libraries. They may be used by GCC and Clang, not by MSVC. The project's build configuration is not correct or not intended for MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

You need remove stdc++fs.lib in Linker -> Input and it will work